# JQuery: Gmap with route

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins, dictionary

I need to work with Gmap plugin using route.
i can set up it on a basic map, but the question is how can i include that functionality in a separate js file?

Here is the very simple example i set it up:

```
http://jsbin.com/iYoKEPa/1
```

But in dev i need to include it in a load() function on a separate js file.
I replicate my dev function on jsbin and try to set the route but was not able to do it:

```
http://jsbin.com/ejimUf/1
```

Someone can help me please.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating two different types of maps between the two documents.
In the first one you are making a Gmaps map and in the second one a google.maps map.

Here it works: http://jsbin.com/ejimUf/3/edit

```
function load(){
  console.log('loaded');
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-12.043333, -77.028333);
  var myMapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,   
    center: point,
    div:'#map',
    lat: -12.043333,
    lng: -77.028333

  };



 map = new GMaps(myMapOptions);



  map.drawRoute({
      origin: [-12.044012922866312, -77.02470665341184],
      destination: [-12.090814532191756, -77.02271108990476],
      travelMode: 'driving',
      strokeColor: '#131540',
      strokeOpacity: 0.6,
      strokeWeight: 6
   });

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!
Can you tell me please what is the difference between a Gmap map and a google.maps.map?
Thank you very much!

Comment: The GMaps which you are including are another library which adds/simplifies some google maps tasks and is provided as an open-source project here: https://github.com/hpneo/gmaps you can probably do what you want with just google maps javascript by checking the documentation here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial and here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference